# OpenCSV : Using a custom filter based on column value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csv, opencsv

I use OpenCSV in order to read CSV file and I use the Java stream method after reading all the rows of CSV file:

```
public class CsvHelper {

    private enum Headers {
        ID,
        NAME,
        EMAIL,
        COUNTRY
    }

    public static List<EmployeeRequest> csvToEmployees(InputStream is) throws IllegalAccessException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
             CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader,
                     CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim())) {

            List<EmployeeRequest> employees = new ArrayList<>();
            Iterable<CSVRecord> records = parser.getRecords();

            for (CSVRecord rec : records) {
                EmployeeRequest employee = new EmployeeRequest(
                        Long.parseLong(rec.get(Headers.ID)),
                        rec.get(Headers.NAME),
                        rec.get(Headers.EMAIL),
                        rec.get(Headers.COUNTRY)
                );
                employees.add(employee);
            }
            return employees;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException("Failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But in order to use the same `csvToEmployees` method multiple times, I need to apply some filter based on some field e.g. `NAME`. I found something on the following page, but not sure if it is the most proper approach for filtering that I mentioned.So, any idea about this issue?

https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBeanFilter.html

Comment: Does anybody have never used filter in OpenCSV?

Comment: You need to try first and show us, then if something is wrong, we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps
List FilterbycoumnValue= new CsvToBeanBuilder
.withFilter(line -> line[1].equals(value))

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation of how the code solves OP's problem?

Comment: OP's problem meaning?

Comment: e.g might help .https://github.com/jagrutifrankdemo/product-aggregator/blob/main/src/main/java/com/ennov/read/impl/CSVFileOpsImpl.java

Comment: "OP's problem" refers to what the Question asker is trying to solve. OP means Original Poster.

Comment: I have given snippet how filter can be achieved during csv read/ post csv read), does that help?